# Finding Records that Have Same Options

Tags: mysql, relational-division

Trying to figure out how find out which user records have at least 1 similar option enabled and then display these.

Tables:

```
user (id, username)
thing (id,title)
uthing (id, uid, tid)
```

Uthing table has a record of what options each user have selected.

```
uid = user.id
tid = thing.id
```

I need to compare the options (`uthing`) from user id 1 with all other users.

How can find users that have 1 or more options(`uthing`) of USER ID 1 and return these users with the options found?

This query will give me all options for user id 1.

```
select thing.title,thing.id as thingid 
from thing join uthing on uthing.tid = thing.id where uthing.uid = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve this by following this query

```
select uthing.id, uthing.uid, thing.title
from uthing left join thing on uthing.tid = thing.id
where uthing.tid in (
        select thing.id
        from thing join uthing on uthing.tid = thing.id
        where uthing.uid = 1
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your schema I've generated next example:

> ```
> create table user (id int, username varchar(100));
> create table thing (id int, title varchar(100));
> create table uthing (id int, uid int, tid int);
>
> insert into user values (1, 'user 1'),(2, 'user 2'),(3, 'user 3'),(4, 'user 4');
> insert into thing values (1, 'thing 1'),(2, 'thing 2'),(3, 'thing 3'),(4, 'thing 4'),(5, 'thing 5');
> insert into uthing values
> (1, 1, 1),(2, 1, 3),
> (3, 2, 2),(4, 2, 3),(5, 2, 5),
> (6, 3, 4),
> (7, 4, 1),(8, 4, 5);
> ```

This query select users where `id <> 1` that has (exists) at least one thing in common with user `id = 1`.

> ```
> select *
> from   user u
> join   uthing ut
> on     ut.uid = u.id
> join   thing t
> on     t.id = ut.tid
> where  u.id <> 1
> and    exists (select 1
>                from   uthing
>                where  uid = 1
>                and    tid = t.id);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | id | uid | tid | id | title  
> -: | :------- | -: | --: | --: | -: | :------
>  2 | user 2   |  4 |   2 |   3 |  3 | thing 3
>  4 | user 4   |  7 |   4 |   1 |  1 | thing 1
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=23f6e368e7faecc66549ab5150ebb51d)*</kbd>